# csrf_protection false option doesn't work while form creation

Tags: php, forms, symfony, csrf-protection

i followed this example to disable csrf protection on form generated in my actionController:
http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/08/symfony-2-how-to-disable-csrf-on-a-per-form-basis/

So i have this action:

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
    {
        $this->focus = "contact";

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $contactPosts = $em->getRepository('VisualImmersionAdminBundle:Post')->findByPostCategory('Contact');
        if (!$contactPosts) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(
            array(
                'csrf_protection' => false
            )
        )
            ->add('Sujet', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' =>false
                )
            )
            ->add('Nom', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' =>false
                )
            )
            ->add('Entreprise', 'text',
                array(
                    'label' =>false
                )
            )
            ->add('Courriel', 'email',
                array(
                    'label' =>false
                )
            )
            ->add('Message', 'textarea',
                array(
                    'label' =>false
                )
            )
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($data['Sujet'] . ' ' . $data['Entreprise'])
                ->setFrom($data['Courriel'])
                ->setTo('contact@visual-immersion.com')
                ->setBody('text à placer par la suite')
            ;
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        }


        return $this->render('VisualImmersionSiteBundle:Site:contact.html.twig',
            array(
                'focus' => $this->focus,
                'form'   => $form->createView(),
                 'contactPosts' => $contactPosts,
            ));
    }
```

and in my twig:

```
div class="semi-container">
                {% if form_errors(form) %}
                    <div class="errors">{{ form_errors(form) }}</div>
                {% endif %}
                <form class="contact-form" action="{{ path('visual_immersion_site_contactpage') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
                    {{ form_row(form.Sujet, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Objet' }}) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.Nom, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Nom' }}) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.Entreprise, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Entreprise' }}) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.Courriel, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Courriel' }}) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.Message, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Message' }}) }}
                    <button type="submit" class="link-know-more">Demander un devis !</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

but the form_errors always returns the error :

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

in my twig view, and mail has not been sent...

I verified with the command cache:clear if the problem was not there, but no, it is not a cache issue.

any idea ?

thanks for your help :)

EDIT:

Ok i solved my initial problem with:

form_rest(form)
for the hidden input.

But with the csrf off, I do not devrasi envoir need, right?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$form->isValid()` without a class as it checks for class constraints.
`handleRequest()` checks for form validation rules, so you'll have to add validations rules to the form builder if you ever need them.

And looking at the tutorial you linked, especially

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($users, array(
    'csrf_protection' => false,  // <---- set this to false on a per Form Instance basis
))->add(...)
;
```

This should be better

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, array(
                'csrf_protection' => false
            ))
```

That's the only things that look wrong to me.

A good alternative to this is to create a dummy entity that you use to create the form but don't persist

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to specify the first parameter because in the function it is setted : createFormBuilder($data = null, array $options = array()). Moreover, the error message stated that he could receive "empty" as parameter

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a long shot. Have you tried without $form->isValid() ?

Comment: @TomToms - $form->isValid() does not require a class.  His problem is that $contactPosts is (one assumes) an array of posts.  So he needs to use a collection and make a form type for an individual post.

Comment: Seems you are right but I don't think the $contactPosts is his problem either

Comment: Well, with the posted code he is not passing any data to the form.  So that is at least one problem.  I suspect he has more.

Comment: Yeah but it seems he is trying to mail a contact form, the $contactPosts is probably just for output. His problem is that the csrf token is required for validation even if he has it set to false.